# django templates {{form.errors}} not showing

Tags: python, django

I have a problem my website.
Please help me.
This is my template folder.

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: #7abecc !important;
        }
        .user_card {
            width: 350px;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            background: #74cfbf;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            border-radius: 5px;

        }

        .form_container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #form-title{
            color: #fff;
        }
        .login_btn {
            width: 100%;
            background: #33ccff !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
        .login_btn:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }
        .login_container {
            padding: 0 2rem;
        }
        .input-group-text {
            background: #f7ba5b !important;
            color: white !important;
            border: 0 !important;
            border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
        }
        .input_user,
        .input_pass:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }

    </style>

{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h3 id="form-title">REGISTER ACCOUNT</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">

                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.username}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.email}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.password1}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.password2}}
                        </div>


                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                            <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Register Account">
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

                {{form.errors}}

                <div class="mt-4">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                        Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="ml-2">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block script %}
    <script>
        var form_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
        form_fields[1].placeholder='Username..';
        form_fields[2].placeholder='Email..';
        form_fields[3].placeholder='Enter password...';
        form_fields[4].placeholder='Re-enter Password...';


        for (var field in form_fields){ 
            form_fields[field].className += ' form-control'
        }
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

and I cant see my web site form.errors and this is my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Article
from .form import ArticleForm,CreateUserForm

#USER


def register(request):
    context = dict()
    context['form'] = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
        
        else:
            context['errors'] = form.errors
            print(form.errors)
        
    return render(request,'page/register.html',context)
```

I see my errors in terminal but not see my web site and If I add {{errors}} to my template file,
I can see on the site like this

```html
    </div>

                {{errors}}

                <div class="mt-4">
```

But I want to use form.errors. What should ı do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the errors because you add the form to the context which does not have any data passed to it, i.e. in your view you have written:

```
context['form'] = CreateUserForm()
```

Hence the `form` present in the context actually has no errors if we consider that it was never passed any data. Instead you should pass the form which you instantiate in case of the POST request in the context:

```
def register(request):
    context = {} # Don't call `dict()`, `{}` will do the same thing
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request,'page/register.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you worked but actually ı cant understand

Comment: I did not understand the difference

Comment: Ya Reis Türkçe biliyorsan türkçe anlatır mısın

Comment: @İbrahimGunes `CreateUserForm()` is a form in which you pass no data, whereas in `CreateUserForm(request.POST)` you pass the POST data of the request. Previously you had written `context['form'] = CreateUserForm()` A form without any data cannot really have any errors, yes? So we have declared the form in the if-else and after both have written `context['form'] = form` so depending on the request the correct form would be passed to the context. And no I don't know turkish (Google translate)

Comment: Okeeyyy I understand Reis türksen yazsana merak ettim eyvallah bu arda

Answer (score 0):

This is how i usually show form errors.
For non field errors:

```
    {% if form.errors %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

For Field errors:

```
{% if form.field_name.errors %}
    {% for error in form.field_name.errors %}
        <div><small style="color: red;">{{ error|escape }}</small></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```